# Data from Mesh to Plutus

Tags: plutus, haskell, types, mesh

I created this datum with Mesh

```
  const datumMD: Data = new Map<Data, Data>();
  datumMD.set('name', assetName );
  datumMD.set('question', input);
  datumMD.set('answers', []);
  datumMD.set('results', []);
  
  const datumState: Data = new Map<Data, Data>();
  datumState.set('state', 'INIT');

  const datumMetadata: Data = {
    alternative: 0,
    fields: [datumMD, datumState]
  };
```

The CBOR of that is:

```
d8799fa447616e737765727380446e616d654a70726f706f73616c2d33487175657374696f6e53446f657320697420776f726b3f20486d6d6d3f47726573756c747380a145737461746544494e4954ff
```

What would the type of that datum be in Plutus (Haskell)?

Comment: When creating `datumMD` you are using keys of type String but values of different types. In Haskell, Maps, just like lists, are **homogenous**, therefore you cannot have lists, then strings, then ... in the same map's values. I cannot help further, correct this and then we'll see how to translate your datum to a Haskell data type. 
Also, I'm interested in why you are doing it this way (Mesh -> Plutus) instead of the usual (Plutus -> Mesh)?

Thanks in advance for the clarification :)

Comment: It seems to work, the CBOR of this datum is this: d8799fa447616e737765727380446e616d654a70726f706f73616c2d31487175657374696f6e576e696b6f73203234206c6570746120706172616b616c7747726573756c747380a145737461746544494e4954ff
So maybe its considered all Map of Data ?

Comment: Could it be that its
data DatumMetadata = DatumMetadata { datumMD       :: ![(BuiltinData, BuiltinData)],
                                                                   datumState    :: ![(BuiltinData, BuiltinData)]}

Comment: I did the Mesh -> Plutus because i needed the datum first on the OffChain part, i didnt use it that much onChain.

Answer (score 0):

also interested, how this Map<Data, Data>() converts to Plutus type? is this (BuiltinData, BuiltinData) a correct way?